# Display the highest num_add in each zip with its hrs score associated in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

[image]

I need to show the highest `num_add` in each zip with its `hrs` score associated.

So `hrs` have multiple values with `num_add` in each zip.

How to only show the highest `num_add` with its `hrs` in each zip?

when I use the below query

```
SELECT query1.hrs, 
       query1.zip, 
       Max(query1.num_add) 
         OVER ( 
           partition BY zip) 
FROM   (SELECT hrs, 
               zip, 
               Count(gid) AS num_add 
        FROM   moziphrs 
        GROUP  BY hrs, 
                  zip 
        ORDER  BY hrs, 
                  zip) query1;
```

it gives me:

[image]

which is still not right. 65340 zip appears twice with hrs 9 and 10. i only want the max num add associated hrs, not all hrs

Desired output:

[image]

Comment: Please add expected result format

Comment: @shockwave added!

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps !

```
SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT HRS, ZIP, COUNT(num_add) OVER (PARTITION BY ZIP order by hrs) as num_add
  FROM MYTABLE) x
order by x.hrs desc
limit 1
```

Comment: When i use '''SELECT query1.hrs,query1.zip,MAX(query1.num_add) OVER (PARTITION BY zip) 
FROM (SELECT hrs,zip,COUNT(gid) AS num_add
 FROM moziphrs
 GROUP BY hrs,zip
 ORDER BY hrs,zip) query1;```
it give me the max number of address but it also give me all the hrs catetory with the same max number of address returned.
however i only want the max num_add associted with the hrs, instead of all the hrs in each zip

Comment: So i acctually want to show the hrs associatied with the max num_add.

Comment: no :(
As you can see it gives me all hrs when i only want the hrs associated with max num_add